# C#: How do i close down my video splash screen after its finished playing

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to close down my splash screen and close down the mediaplayer and finally open the login screen. However, the media player stays open and does not close and can't quite figure it out. If someone can help i would be very grateful. (Also just learning C# but i have spent a couple of hours googling the answer)

```
    public SplashScreen()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void SplashScreen_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Splash.uiMode = "None";
        Splash.URL = @"D:\\Downloads\\Splash.wmv";


        if (Splash.playState == WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsStopped)
        {
            Splash.close();

            LogIn login = new LogIn();
            login.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

...

Comment: The `Load()` event only fires ONCE, when the form LOADS.  I doubt the "Splash" player is actually playing the video at that point.  Try wiring up the `PlayStateChange` event of your "Splash" player and check the "playState" from there.

Comment: thanks but i figured i will think outside of the box somewhat and look at it another way by seeing if I could set a timer on the form and close it down when my splash animation finishes and lo and behold that worked :)